# How to get sorted input from an csv file?

Tags: python, csv, sorting, input, extract

I have a problem according to taking and fetching input from a CSV file, let's say for example I have a CSV file as follows:-

```
product_name,category
canon camera,DSLR
hikvision camera,security
cp plus camera,security
```

The above is my CSV file now I have to write a python script from which I can sort product_names according to the category.

I just want that I have some list as securitys, DSLRs, etc. I just want that there should be 's' after the category value as securitys etc. and they all must be a list and in securitys list, the values must be like product names hikivison camera, cp plus camera, etc..and DSLRs list value is canon camera, and I want it dynamic means in future if I add some more categories along with their product_names I can dynamically get more lists according to their categories + 's' and the list contains the value of product names which fall in the category.
I tried too many times with different approaches but it is not working.
need serious help!
Thank you!

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Show what have you tried (your best attempt, [mre]), any traceback you get. Also, you know, this meaning of `security` has no plural form, while otherwise it would be `securities`.

Comment: sorry for that I tried                                                                                                                   import pandas as pd                                                                                                                  df = pd.read_csv('main_in.csv') then a=df.sort_values("category") then security_pds = [] then ip_pds = [] then for pro,cat in a.values:
    if cat == 'security':
        security_pds.append(pro)
    if cat == 'ip':
        ip_pds.append(pro)  but my output is ok like security_pds, ip_pds and the product values based on that.

Comment: To sort the file, use a [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) to read its contents and create a list-of-rows (each row itself being a list of field values). You can then sort that the outer list using the built-in [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function in conjunction with `key` argument specifying a function that controls which fields are used when comparing them to one another (which controls how the sorting done). Also see the [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sorting-how-to) section.

Comment: Can you please explain me clearly or with a live example because I am getting the list of lists containing the fields and their values but I don't know how I can use this to sort it.

Comment: Your question is about using pandas and dataframes, so it should be tagged as such. You need to also add the code of your attempt to _it_ — not down here in a comment. As for giving you an example: sorry, I am not familiar with using either.